# Can I disable the "Disable apps to help improve performance" notification?

Tags: windows-10, notification-area

I've been running the released version of Windows 10 (x64) for a week now. Every other day or so, I get the following Security and Maintenance notification regarding "disable apps to help improve performance":

[image: Windows 10 Action Center]

My machine has 12 cores and 32GB of RAM--I really am not experiencing any slowdown. Note: when you click the notification, it shows Task Manager on the Startup tab where you can disable items in the startup--I don't want or need this.

The apps that display as having a High Startup impact are apps that I want to load at startup.

In previous Windows versions, if the Action Center had a message about Anti-Virus protection or Windows Update or Backups, you could go into the Action Center and tell it to not bother you with any more messages about it.

How can I tell windows not to bug me about this non-issue?

**Edit:** A couple of suggestions that didn't work:

- Right-click the notification and then choose never to receive that type of notification any more. *NOPE*
- Control Panel -> System and Security -> Security and Maintenance -> Change Security and Maintenance Settings -> Startup Apps. *Unfortunately Startup apps is disabled (and checked)*

Comment: What is your question exactly.  Have you determine if you actually want those 3 application to automatically start?

Comment: @Ramhound: The question is how do I keep this B.S. notification from popping up again. The apps that show as high impact are apps that I would never want to disable--they're in startup because I want them there.

Comment: @C-PoundGuru I have a feeling this is local GPO related. I'm domain joined on my home PCs (Yes, that kind of dork) so I'll have to play around with it to see if I can find if there's any policies preventing that from being disabled.

Comment: @C-PoundGuru, quoting is better.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It was driving me crazy, too.  I found the answer in a comment from Troy Dallas on [thurrott.com](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/5084/windows-10-tip-manage-notifications):

> Once you get the `Disable apps to help improve performance` notification:
>
> Go to `Control Panel -> Security and Maintenance` (right click on the Start Button and Left click on `Control Panel` to jump straight there).
>
> Once opened under `Maintenance` (middle of the window) you will see the notification box with a Blue link at the bottom of the
>   notification. Click that link `Turn off messages about startup apps`.

**Important Note:** The notification has to be in the Notifications Window before it will appear in the `Security and Maintenance` section.

Comment: I was able to follow this after dismissing the message. The link still appeared in the Security and Maintenance panel.

Comment: To get to that menu and remove the annoyance: Hit start menu and start typing "maintenance"